# Cron Syntax For Jenkins To Run Ever 5 Minutes But Not Run For 1 Hour 1 Day A Week

Tags: jenkins, cron, cronexpression

I would like to run a Jenkins job every 5 minutes, but once a week not run anything, for an hour.

For example, every Monday I wouldn't want the project to be triggered from 10:00PM - 11:00PM. Every other day every other hour it should run every 5 minutes.

This is what I have right now:

```
H/5 0-21,23 * * 0-6
```

But I'm having trouble with closing the window on only one selected day. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need complex stuff not supported by `cron`, I tend to just code it at the top of the script itself:

```
dow_hour=$(date +%u%H)
if [[ ${dow_hour} = "122" ]] ; then # Mondays, 10:xx PM
    exit
fi
```

Alternatively, there's nothing stopping you from having *multiple* `cron` entries for the same job, if you want locality of control:

```
H/5 *       * * 0,2-6 blah blah blah # continuously on non-mondays
H/5 0-21,23 * * 1     blah blah blah # not between 10/11pm on mondays
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using two crontab entries? One for all days except Monday and one for Monday only?

```
H/5 * * * 0,2-6
H/5 0-21,23 * * 1
```